# Cannot get boostraps jQuery tooltips to appear

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Starting to get frustrated which is making it harder to see where I might be going wrong, but essentially I'm trying to get Bootstrap's jQuery tooltips to work upon hovering over an image in the content of my page.

HTML in body:

```
<div class="tooltip-demo well">
<a title="Tooltip Text Goes Here" rel="tooltip" class="pennant-task" href="#">
<img src="/ssawp/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/images/tasks/ytool-boatparts.jpg" />
</a>
</div>
```

Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tooltip-demo.well').tooltip({
        selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
    })
</script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've shortened the paths to make it easier to browse, but feel free to check out the problem **live** on:

```
http://okamistudio.com/ssawp/pennants/
```

I'm trying to achieve the tooltip on the small boat icon underneath the 'Yellow Pennant' block of text.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to include `bootstrap.js` before you write your own code. Secondly you need to wrap your code in a document ready handler.

Also, you haven't included it in your example, so for the sake of completeness I've included the required `jquery.js` too. Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.tooltip-demo.well').tooltip({
            selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had the bootstrap.js included (see in the bottom of the second source snippet), was missing the document ready handler (if that's the $function() { bit) and it seems I've been using an outdate version of jQuery (1.2.3) which wasn't helping either.

Thank you for that, I don't have much working knowledge of JS at all which is why I missed that opening bit. Would you mind just briefly explaining what it does - creates it into a function as opposed to plain script?

I have to wait 8mins to answer but you solved it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. The document ready handler (you're corerct, it's the `$(function() { ... });` wrapper) means that the code within that block is not executed until the DOM is ready. Previously your code was looking for the `.tooltip-demo.well` element in the DOM before it existed, which is why it did not work.

Comment: Aha, fantastic. Thank you for taking the time to explain that! Have a great day.